# Inject Style-sheet into Iframe (Facebook Like Box)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook-like

We are trying to style a Facebook like box which annoyingly has fixed image widths/heights set and borders which ruin our design.  We would like to overwrite a couple of the styles to suit.

The Likebox is embedded using an iframe.

Is it possible to inject a stylesheet into an IFrame?  Using Javascript possibly?  Or does anyone have any other suggestions?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it yourself. You can styling everything of Facebook Like Box with custom CSS code. Visit this tutorial at: [DaddyDesign: Styling Facebook Like Box](http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-your-facebook-fan-box/)

Comment: This only applies to the deprecated FBML version of the like box.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, you can't inject CSS, and that's by design.

The [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents you from accessing or modifying the content in the iframe.

---

You can add `height` and `width` and `data-border-color` attributes to your `<iframe>` to tell Facebook what size and border color you'd like (subject to minimums).  Set the border color to match your background to make it look like there's no border.

See [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) for more info.